# How to emit a message to the sockets from an API endpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have socket.io set up and working and now I need to send updates to the users via the same sockets, the updates I get from a different server (the other server makes a GET http request to my nodejs server and I need to take the data from that http request and emit it to a certain user via sockets)

Here's my code, emitting sockets from inside the socket process works fine but from inside the API call doen't work.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require("http").createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

app.set('socketIo', io);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("User connected: ", socket.id);    
    io.to(socket.id).emit("new_message", {id: "999", msg: "You are connected, your Id is " + socket.id});
})

app.get("/send/:id/:message", (request, result) => {
    const ioEmitter = request.app.get("socketIo");
    ioEmitter.to(request.params.id).emit({ id: "999", msg: request.params.message });
    result.send("Sending message to socket Id: " + request.params.id)
    console.log("Sending message to socket Id: " + request.params.id);
})

const port = 3001;
http.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Listening to port " + port);
});
```

Comment: In the second call to `emit` you haven't specified the event name (`new_message`)

Comment: @Titus Oh wow I'm so stupid.. Tried it and now it works perfectly, Thank you!!